# Why tensor has different shape on second call of 'call' function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

Let me introduce you:
I'm trying to run Fast-RCNN algorithm with RoiPoolingLayer written in tensorflow.keras.

Here is the current code of RoIPoolingLayer:

```
class RoiPoolingConv(Layer):
    """
    Define ROI Pooling Convolutional Layer for 2D inputs.
    """

    def __init__(self, pool_size, num_rois, **kwargs):
        self.pool_size = pool_size
        self.num_rois = num_rois
        self.nb_channels = None

        super(RoiPoolingConv, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.nb_channels = input_shape[0][3]

        super(RoiPoolingConv, self).build(input_shape)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return None, self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        assert (len(x) == 2)

        # x[0] is image with shape (rows, cols, channels)
        img = x[0]
        # x[1] is roi with shape (num_rois,4) with ordering (x,y,w,h)
        rois = x[1]

        outputs = []
        print('image shape', img)
        print('roi shape', rois, self.num_rois)
        for roi_idx in range(self.num_rois):
            x = rois[0, roi_idx, 0]
            y = rois[0, roi_idx, 1]
            w = rois[0, roi_idx, 2]
            h = rois[0, roi_idx, 3]

            x = tf.cast(x, tf.int32)
            y = tf.cast(y, tf.int32)
            w = tf.cast(w, tf.int32)
            h = tf.cast(h, tf.int32)

            rs = tf.image.resize(img[:, y:y + h, x:x + w, :],
                                 (self.pool_size, self.pool_size))
            outputs.append(rs)

        print(outputs, 'before concatenate', outputs.__len__())
        final_output = K.concatenate(outputs, axis=0)
        print(final_output, '\nreshape to: ', (1, self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels))
        final_output = K.reshape(final_output, (1, self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels))
        final_output = K.permute_dimensions(final_output, (0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

        return final_output

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'pool_size': self.pool_size,
                  'num_rois': self.num_rois}
        base_config = super(RoiPoolingConv, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

As you can see I'm trying to debug this code, that's why I print some code.
Line:
`final_output = K.reshape(final_output, (1, self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels))`
Is invoking an error, which tells me I can't reshape:

> Cannot reshape a tensor with 3211264 elements to shape [1,4,7,7,512] (100352 elements) for '{{node model/roi_pooling_conv/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](model/roi_pooling_conv/concat, model/roi_pooling_conv/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [128,7,7,512], [5] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1,4,7,7,512].

I tried to debug this stuff and the interesting part is in `call` function.
Let me paste the output so I'll describe it later:

```
image shape Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 7, 7, 512), dtype=float32)
roi shape Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None, None, 4), dtype=float32) 4
[<tf.Tensor 'roi_pooling_conv/resize/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(None, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'roi_pooling_conv/resize_1/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(None, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'roi_pooling_conv/resize_2/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(None, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'roi_pooling_conv/resize_3/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(None, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>] before concatenate 4
Tensor("roi_pooling_conv/concat:0", shape=(None, 7, 7, 512), dtype=float32) 
reshape to:  (1, 4, 7, 7, 512)
image shape Tensor("model/block5_pool/MaxPool:0", shape=(32, 7, 7, 512), dtype=float32)
roi shape Tensor("model/Cast:0", shape=(32, 16, 4), dtype=float32) 4
[<tf.Tensor 'model/roi_pooling_conv/resize/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(32, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'model/roi_pooling_conv/resize_1/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(32, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'model/roi_pooling_conv/resize_2/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(32, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'model/roi_pooling_conv/resize_3/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(32, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32>] before concatenate 4
Tensor("model/roi_pooling_conv/concat:0", shape=(128, 7, 7, 512), dtype=float32) 
reshape to:  (1, 4, 7, 7, 512)
```

So, I have 2 inputs, feature map and rois. Shape of feature map on first `call` is `None, 7, 7, 512`, in second call is `32, 7, 7, 512`.

Why? I have input of 32 images, with input_shape `224x224x3`. Does it mean, I have wrong preprocessed data?

Btw. Data I'm delivering, is MS COCO 2014, I'm loading image by cv2, resizing it to `224x224` and later some numpy operations:

```
        # get RGB from BGR
        resized_image = resized_image[:, :, (2, 1, 0)]
        resized_image = resized_image.astype(numpy.float32)
        resized_image[:, :, 0] -= 103.939
        resized_image[:, :, 1] -= 116.779
        resized_image[:, :, 2] -= 123.68
        resized_image /= 1.0
        resized_image = numpy.transpose(resized_image, (2, 0, 1))
        resized_image = numpy.expand_dims(resized_image, axis=0)
        resized_image = numpy.transpose(resized_image, (0, 2, 3, 1))

        print('image size: ', resized_image.shape)
        _train_images.append(resized_image)
```

and `append` to array.

Before delivering to CNN, I'm doing `numpy.asarray` (tried before `numpy.array`)
Roi, is basically done on resized image by selective search, in `x, y, w, h` format. It's kept as tuple in array (array of tuples) and before delivering it also I'm doing `numpy.assarray()`. Doing 16 RoI per image - just to make it fast, I want first have this code working properly, later make 2000 rois per image.
Is data wrong preprocessed?
I feel like, the first `call` is done on 'no data' and then the second `call` receives an array of images. Can somebody at least tell what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you first run the call method or the fit method of an instance of the Model class, it first calls the build method, which in turn will call the build methods of the layers. The size of an input tensor with `input_shape = (7, 7, 512)` will be set to (None, 7, 7, 512), None corresponding to the (unknown) batch size. Later, the size of this tensor will be replaced by (batch_size, 7, 7, 512) with batch_size=32 in your case.
In the first, the model weights are set and initialized, and the network graph is created. Then, everything works "normally" with the first dimension of the input tensors set to the batch_size (a number).
In your case, you specified `input_shape = (None, 4)` for the roi tensor, right?
At the end of your layer, you get a tensor of size (128, 7, 7, 512) after concatenation along axis 0 (the batch axis). So you can't reshape it to (1, 4, 7, 7, 512).
You could maybe reshape it to (32, 4, 7, 7, 512) like this :

```
final_output = K.reshape(final_output, (K.shape(img)[0], self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels))
```

Note the use of `K.shape(img)[0]` to cope with the value None.